# Does graph Change Notification on Groups work if users are added to nested Security Groups?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-notifications

I have a Group which contains multiple nested groups. If users are removed/added from the nested Groups, and I have change notification subscribed on the Parent Group, will I still get the notifications with the delta members.

I have given an example of my scenario below:

```
TestParentGroup
   ChildGroup-1
       User 1
       User 2
   ChildGroup-2
       User 3
       User 4
```

Change notification is subscribed on `TestParentGroup`. If I remove User 4 and add a new Group to `ChildGroup-2`, will I get the notification with the delta members (i.e. User-4 + all members of new Group that has been added) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your scenario you should received a notification for the ChildGroup if you subscribe for it but not for the parent group, the change notifications do not propagate changes across nested objects.

Comment: Thanks. This answers what I was looking for.